# rp_filter was set to 1 unexpectedly on rhel 9 clones

Tags: networking, sysctl, rhel9

I'm trying to setup a virtual interface, and disable its rp_filter.
For example, a virtual ethernet:

```
ip l a va type veth peer name vb; echo 0 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4//conf/va/rp_filter
```

It works fine on centos 7 and rocky 8, but the rp_filter was set to 1 automatically on rocky 9 & alma 9, even the default of rp_filter was set to 0.
When setting rp_filter immediately after creating a virtual interface including virtual ether and ipip and dummy and so on, the rp_filter will be set to 1 in a short time on rhel 9 clones. But, if I set the value later, it will work as expected.
Is there any setting that I have overlooked?

Thank you very much.

Comment: You can run simulateneously in an other terminal: `ip -ts monitor netconf` to see when the revert happens (but it won't tell what did it). Might still give a hint.

Comment: I'd say at random that could be systemd networkd. systemd already changes the MAC address of new virtual interfaces (run `ip -ts monitor link` instead to witness it), why not also do this? (eg: https://github.com/systemd/systemd/pull/28391/commits/9c72e8f8bc495f1c4272ad9119146f89c9903cab )

Comment: It takes 5ms to change back to 1 on two of my machines...